# Are digest cycle and digest loop identical?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

I was going through digest cycles (and loops) and getting to know about `$apply`, `$digest` and so on. However, in some articles they refer digest cycles the same as digest loops. I know that there will be at least two iterations for any `$apply`.  What are those iterations called (digest cycles or digest loops).

If they are different, are they related? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same - it is the background process `AngularJs` uses to detect changes.